# error al pasar datos de un pdo statement a un array : Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statements

trato de pasar los datos de una consulta a un array para luego establecerlos en un token pero me sale el siguiente error: `Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`

```
public function obtenerDatosCliente($correo_electronico){
  try {
            $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
            $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT codigo_cliente, nombre, apellido, correo_electronico, estado FROM cliente WHERE correo_electronico = ?");
            $consulta->execute([$correo_electronico]);
            $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);

            return array(
           'Id'=>$consulta->fetch()->codigo_cliente,
           'Nombre'=>$consulta->fetch()->nombre,
           'Apellido'=>$consulta->fetch()->apellido,
           'Correo electronico'=>$consulta->fetch()->correo_electronico,
           'estado'=>$consulta->fetch()->estado,
    );

        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo('Se produjo un error al obtener los datos del cliente: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: En que linea te esta dando? La idea del error es que estas intentando acceder a alguna propiedad de un objeto, cuando no esta definido como tal. puede ser que sea nulo o que realmente sea un array...

Comment: en todas las lineas dentro del array me sale el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error dice que no es un objeto, Porque [`fetch()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.fetch.php) devuelve un `array` indexado y no un objeto, entonces para obtener el valor deberías hacer, por ejemplo `->fetch()['key']`.

```
public function obtenerDatosCliente($correo_electronico){
  try {
            $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->conectar();
            $consulta = $conexion->prepare("SELECT codigo_cliente, nombre, apellido, correo_electronico, estado FROM cliente WHERE correo_electronico = ?");
            $consulta->execute([$correo_electronico]);
            $conexion = $this->clase_dbconexion->desconectar($conexion);

            return array(
           'Id'=>$consulta->fetch()['codigo_cliente'],
           'Nombre'=>$consulta->fetch()['nombre'],
           'Apellido'=>$consulta->fetch()['apellido'],
           'Correo electronico'=>$consulta->fetch()['correo_electronico'],
           'estado'=>$consulta->fetch()['estado'],
    );

        } catch (PDOException $exception) {
            echo('Se produjo un error al obtener los datos del cliente: ' . $exception->getMessage());
        }
```

Una mejor práctica sería pasar el `fetch()` a una variable nueva y llamarlo de ahí.

```
$fetch = $consulta->fetch();
return array(
   'Id'=>$fetch['codigo_cliente'],
   'Nombre'=>$fetch['nombre'],
   'Apellido'=>$fetch['apellido'],
   'Correo electronico'=>$fetch['correo_electronico'],
   'estado'=>$fetch['estado'],
);
```

Si quisieras usarlo como objecto, deberías pasarle en el `fetch()` la constante `PDO::FETCH_OBJ`.

```
$fetch = $consulta->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
return array(
   'Id'=>$fetch->codigo_cliente,
   'Nombre'=>$fetch->nombre,
   'Apellido'=>$fetch->apellido,
   'Correo electronico'=>$fetch->correo_electronico,
   'estado'=>$fetch->estado,
);
```

Comment: en tu primer ejemplo me sale el siguiente error: `Error grave: Error no detectado: No se puede usar el objeto de tipo stdClass como matriz en C: \ xampp \ htdocs \ `

Comment: Si hacés un `var_dump($consulta->fetch())` qué te devuelve?

Comment: @Leonidas con los otros ejemplos te funciona?

Comment: si, con los otros ejemplos funciona, es suficiente, gracias.